# Encode HTML in Flex/Actionscript

Tags: html, apache-flex

Are there any functions available to convert:

```
Me, Myself & I
```

to

```
Me, Myself &amp; I
```

I can't find anything in the Flex documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Check [this](http://www.razorberry.com/blog/archives/2007/11/02/converting-html-entities-in-as3/) out.  No swc's to include.  Basically it's

var s:String = new XMLNode(3, "Me, Myself & I").toString();

Comment: It's worth noting: I believe this is AS2.

Comment: Well, escaping XML isn't exactly escaping HTML  For instance I would like \n to be converted into <br>.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the AS3 solution:

```
import flash.xml.XMLNode;
import flash.xml.XMLNodeType;

public function htmlEscape(str:String):String {
    return XML( new XMLNode( XMLNodeType.TEXT_NODE, str ) ).toXMLString();
}
```

Source: http://www.razorberry.com/blog/archives/2007/11/02/converting-html-entities-in-as3/

Answer (score -3):

Escape should do it:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/package.html#escape%28%29

Comment: escape() does URL encoding, not HTML encoding.