# Actionscript encode, C# decode XML

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, serialization, flash-builder, deserialization

I have a XML string in Actionscript (FlashBuilder). I am encoding it using escape(str) and sending it to C# using web services.

Now, I want to deserialize this string but the problem is, when I decode the string it decodes everything inlcuding "&" and then the XMLSerializer complains.

And if I don't decode it then the deserialized string comes with %20 instead of spaces.

Is there an easy way of decoding the escaped string in C# to feed into XML Serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing URL-encoding with XML/HTML-encoding. actionscript's `escape` method URL-encodes. To XML/HTML-encode see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342453/encode-html-in-flex-actionscript).