# decode special characters within div to display them without conflicting with javascript or parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character-encoding, uri

I am generating html page from an adobe air application. users will be entering comments and I am generating them inside a div in the HTML. I have used a function that converts special characters to uriencoded format (@ - _ . * + / these are not encoded). Now when i view the html page i can see only the encoded uri values. how can i convert them back to regular string in html (without any consequences) below is how my generated div looks like.

```
<div class="caption" id="captiondiv" style="display: block">
  <span class="closeCaptionButton">
    <img src="../source/images/closebutton.png"/>
  </span>
  %3C%3E%2C./%3F%22%3E%21@%23%24%25%5E%26*%28%29_+-%3D%60%7E%5B%5D%5C%7B%7D%7C%3B%27%3A%22%0DI%20am%20done%20with%20the%20comments
</div>
```

My intention is to generate html that displays the text within div without any problem even if the user inputs some special character. suggest me if there is a better solution.

Adding an image to show how my div looks in browser
[image: This is how it looks in browser]

Comment: below link help me to solve my issue
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14059981/334091