# Replace < and > symbols with &lt; and &gt; symbols in HTML String

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want Regular expression for replace < and > symbols by &lt; and &gt; in html text and make as a valid XML.

Example String:

```
<HTML><BODY><p style="margin:0px">His <span style="color: rgb(237, 23, 23);">career </span>spanned the development of cinema, from <span style="font-weight: 700;">silent film</span>, through early experiments in <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Technicolor </span>to filmmaking in the 21st century.​</p><p>His career spanned the development of cinema, from silent film, through early experiments in Technicolor to filmmaking in the 21st century.<This sample></p>​</BODY></HTML>
```

Result:

```
<HTML><BODY><p style="margin:0px">His <span style="color: rgb(237, 23, 23);">career </span>spanned the development of cinema, from <span style="font-weight: 700;">silent film</span>, through early experiments in <span style="text-transform: uppercase;">Technicolor </span>to filmmaking in the 21st century.​</p><p>His career spanned the development of cinema, from silent film, through early experiments in Technicolor to filmmaking in the 21st century.&lt;This sample&gt;</p>​</BODY></HTML>
```

Thanks

Iyyappan S

Comment: What language are you using? If you're using PHP, you can use `htmlentities` to encode all special characters.

Comment: I am using action script 3.0 in flex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342453/570812

Comment: When I pass this string to XML get Invalid XML error because of '<This sample>' so i want to convert this symbols before convert to XML.

Comment: Will the text between the `<` and `>` always have a space? If not, you will need a full list of XML tags to use in the RegEx

Comment: This text entered by user. User can enter < or > or both symbols.I have xml error entering these symbols.

Comment: Where does the user enter this? Shouldn't `<` and `>` already be escaped by the user input?

Comment: This text entered in textarea.

Comment: An HTML `<textarea>`? Then where does all the HTML come from? You should just escape user input before injecting into HTML/XML. Trying to extract it later is not the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

That should do it:

```
private function replaceTags(string:String):String
{
    string = string.replace(/</gi, "&lt;");
    string = string.replace(/>/gi, "&gt;");

    return string;
}

trace("Replaced string: " + replaceTags("String < with >"));
```

Another option would be to wrap your text into CDATA in XML

Comment: This will also replace html tags. I want replace only < and > symbols not included in HTML tags supported by flex.

Comment: Oh, that's a challenge :) Wouldn't it help if you wrap the whole HTML part into CDATA when you pass it to the XML - without modifying anything?

Comment: I want convert whole HTML part into XML.